# RAM used per mb in R workspace

Tags: r

Is there any way of telling how much RAM is used per mb stored in the workspace in R?

I've got ~700 mb of stuff in the workspace and it brings my pc to a complete freeze, even though it has 4GB of ram, on Ubuntu which is a lightweight OS.

This is just data, I am just doing basic exploratory stats on it like plotting, averaging e.t.c

Comment: With a few exceptions, every time you use objects in R, copies are made. This is partly to ensure operations can take place without side effects. If you are regularly operating on 700Mb worth of objects, it is likely that you will be making use of multiples of this in actual RAM.

Comment: @James - unless the OP has verified that a lot of RAM is allocated to `R`, this is not a memory problem.  He needs to provide a lot more info about "complete freeze" before this can be diagnosed.

Comment: I ran top and checked, it uses all the memory. Why would you need verification of this? I don't know what else would cause a process running to slow down a system.

Comment: It's not easy to predict how much memory an operation on an object will need. It really depends on the operation. Your options are getting more RAM or modifying your code to need less memory.

Comment: @Roland How could I modify the code to use less memory? I'm storing 700mb of data in the workspace then analysing it : making graphs statistics e.t.c Do you mean at the point of analysis?

Comment: Well, without knowing exactly what you are doing, it's not possible to suggest alternatives. Every time you do something with an object in your workspace, you need additional memory for that. That should be obvious.

Comment: @user1987097 you need to provide specfic examples, as it depends on the specfic code you use wether or not copies will be made etc.

Comment: A rough rule of thumb is that you need 3 times the amount of RAM for each Mb data you have. Of course this does not always work, but it provides a good first estimate.

Comment: As said already earlier, it depends on what you do with your data. You don't need 700mb of stuff to flood your memory, just type `toy <- sample(100000); huge <- toy %*% t(toy)` and you will probably run out of memory... Maybe the command `object.size` is helpful to find large objects. If your "basic stuff" contains a covariance matrix, you might run in above mentioned situation.